# Changing MySQL master host on slave and preserving MASTER_LOG_POS, MASTER_LOG_FILE

Tags: mysql-replication

Folks, my master MySQL server got an additional NIC used for local networking and now I want all slave servers to use the new local IP of the master server.

I know I can achieve this using "CHANGE MASTER TO..." command but it has a side-effect: if master host is changed MASTER_LOG_POS and MASTER_LOG_FILE are reset.

Of course, I can re-set these variables manually but I wonder if there is a better way? Is it possible to change the master host on slave and preserve these variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using IP address in the 'change master to', then you can use the hosts file to redirect your traffic w/out touching your mysql.